# Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality(e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly. even there is no error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

```
2019-08-02 17:52:49,535 [J pool 3/7]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - Android Studio 3.4.2  Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5692245 
2019-08-02 17:52:49,587 [J pool 3/7]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-08-02 17:52:49,588 [J pool 3/7]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - OS: Windows 10 
2019-08-02 17:52:49,588 [J pool 3/7]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - Plugin to blame: Kotlin version: 1.3.41-release-Studio3.4-1 
2019-08-02 17:52:49,589 [J pool 3/7]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - Last Action: EditorPaste 
2019-08-02 17:52:49,590 [J pool 3/7]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - Could not initialize class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.TypeUtils 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.TypeUtils
```

Answer (score 0):

try to downgrade gradle and kotlin version

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
 classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.10'
```